# send vendor id and poduct id for linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, module, linux-device-driver

I making a simple experimental device usb.
I making a simples module driver for linux kernel

my usb_driver.h:

```
#ifndef __USB_DRIVER_H__
#define __USB_DRIVER_H__

#define USB_SKEL_VENDOR_ID "7SEG_DRIVER"
#define USB_SKEL_PRODUCT_ID 0x0001

static int skel_probe(struct usb_interface *intf, const struct usb_device_id *id);
static void skel_disconnect(struct usb_interface *intf);

static struct usb_device_id skel_table[] = {
    { USB_DEVICE(USB_SKEL_VENDOR_ID, USB_SKEL_PRODUCT_ID) },
    { }
};


static struct usb_driver skel_driver = {
    .name = "skeleton",
    .probe = skel_probe,
    .disconnect = skel_disconnect,
    .id_table = skel_table,
};

#endif
```

my usb_driver.c:

```c
#include "usb_driver.h"

MODULE_AUTHOR("SEU NOME <seu_email@email.com>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Introducao a criacao de driver pra linux");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_VERSION("1.0");
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(usb, skel_table);

static int skel_probe(struct usb_interface *intf, 
        const struct usb_device_id *id) 
{
    pr_info("o usb 7segmento foi conectado");
    return 0;
}

static void skel_disconnect(struct usb_interface *intf)
{  
    pr_info("o usb 7segmento foi desconectado");
}

static int __init usb_skel_init(void)
{
    //registrando este driver com subsistema USB
    int result = usb_register(&skel_driver);
    if(result < 0) {
        pr_err("usb_register falhou para o driver %s. Erro numero %s"
                , skel_driver.name, result);
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit usb_skel_exit(void)
{
    usb_deregister(&skel_driver);
    pr_info("Modulo removido\n");
}

module_init(usb_skel_init);
module_exit(usb_skel_exit);
```

My "usb device" is very simple. I only connect Vcc and GND in a LED for work indicator. And i connect G+ and G- in a arduino for send any data. I dont started a write code in arduino.

My doube is: HOW I SEND TO KERNEL MY VENDOR_ID AND PRODUCT_ID for kernel call my probe function??   How my usb device send to kernel a vendor_id and product_id ??

```
            ven_id            list_vend_id[]
```

[ DEVICE USB ] ========> [KERNEL] ===============> [call skel_probe();]

Comment: `USB_DEVICE` macro expects numberic value for Vendor ID, not a string. Take a look how it's used in other drivers. What do you mean by *send vendor_id and product_id to kernel*? Also why do you declare static variables in header?

Comment: @dimich i declare static variable because i want that variavel has a file scope.

Comment: @dimich
When i say "send vendor_id and product_id" is because the kernel require a product_id and vendor_id to call the probe function. The kernel find the correct probe function  through the vendor_id and product_id. How the kernel do know that connected device is a device assign to specific vendor_id and product_id in list usb_device_id

Comment: I think that the device must send your product_id and vendor_id for kernel, and the kernel find the correct probe function. If this is not  like this, then i want know how do the kernel find the correct probe function of the my device driver. If i sended my vendor_id and product_id for struct usb_device_id, now when i connect my usb device the kernel must identify that the device connected is assign to vendor_id XXX and product_id YYYY and call the function vendor_XXX_product_yyy_probe();

Comment: You can declare `skel_table` and `skel_driver` in `usb_driver.c`. I don't think you want to register driver twice from different places. For simple driver header is not needed at all.

Comment: Firmware in your device should report it's vendor ID, product ID, device class etc to USB core. Then USB core dispatches probe call to a driver which registered corresponding VID:PID. What is displayed in kernel log when you're plugging in the device? Is the device present in `lsusb` output?

Comment: @dimich i think that i wronged, because i dont explaining correct. The device usb is make by me.  I created a new device usb for a specific task. So the device dont has a vendor_id, i need create a vendor_id e learn send this to kernel

Comment: So you have no USB device yet. What Arduino model to you use? What firmware is flashed? Your USB device must implement USB stack. It may be either hardware or software implementation (e.g. [V-USB](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html)). You need refer to documentation for your device/firmware how to specify VID:PID. Another question is how to select VID:PID. For commercial use you have to purchase one. For personal use or testing you can use default VID:PID set in your device USB stack firmware or assing some unused.

Comment: You could also use one of the "Test PIDs" and associated vendor ID from [pid.codes](https://pid.codes/) if you are just experimenting. They are listed [here](https://pid.codes/pids/). If it turns into an open source hardware project, you can request a permament PID from them.

Comment: well, i has a VID and PID.  Now i need discover how to send this for host. The usb pinout has a four cables. VCC (+5v), GND, DATA- and DATA+ ...   The DATA- and DATA+ are do send and received data. I need learn how use DATA- and DATA+ for send my vid and pid. When i connect send this concatenated in a string? i need send this splited? i need that the kernel ask for me which the vid and pid? How do I continue the process?

Comment: @GuilhermeGiácomoSimoes USB doesn't work the way you think. You can't just send out VID:PID like over serial port. Please learn how USB works. You can start with [USB in a NutShell](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml).

Comment: I have no idea what hardware you are using, but since you mentioned Arduino, you may be interested in [z0nt/VUSB](https://github.com/z0nt/VUSB).